# Pick the earliest date record

Tags: oracle

I have a doubt in Oracle SQl, I have to pick the earliest record based on date ranges.  I have table A with

```
NAME.A  SHOPNO  YEAR.A shop key 
XX         123  2013     1
YY         345  2013     2
```

I have table b with two columns .

```
SHOPNO     NUMBER.B NAME.B  INSERT_DATE.B
  1         987     ZZ      7/13/2013
  2         456     ZZ      12/1/2013
```

My resulting output should be

```
NAME.A  SHOPNO  YEAR.A  NUMBER.B    NAME.B
XX         123    2013       987        ZZ
```

Please let me know how it can be achieved in oracle sql

Comment: Please format the data in your question so that it is readable.

Comment: What do you mean by NAME.A?  Dots are not allowed in column names in Oracle. If you are changing your actual column names to something generic, that is OK, but you must still follow the syntax rules. Then: What do you mean by "earliest record **based on date ranges**"? What "date ranges"? What do you mean by "based on" such ranges?

Comment: I have a doubt in Oracle SQl, I have to pick the earliest record based on date ranges. I have table A with NAME_A SHOPNO YEAR_A shop key XX 123 2013 1 YY 345 2013 2

I have table b with two columns . SHOPNO NUMBER.B NAME.B INSERT_DATE_B 1 987 ZZ 7/13/2013 2 456 ZZ 12/1/2013

My resulting output should be NAME.A SHOPNO YEAR.A NUMBER.B NAME.B XX 123 2013 987 ZZ

Please let me know how it can be achieved in oracle sql

Comment: I apologize, I am trying to get the correct record from Table B based on the year in table A. In table A, ,my year is 2013 and when I am looking for the corresponding row in table B for my table A year, I have two rows from the same year. From those two rows, I have to pick the earliest row .which is shown in resulting set.  I have table A with NAME_A SHOPNO YEAR_A shop key XX 123 2013 1 YY 345 2013 2

I have table b with two columns . SHOPNO NUMBER.B NAME.B INSERT_DATE_B 1 987 ZZ 7/13/2013 2 456 ZZ 12/1/2013

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer from a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11439094/3061852) for a more efficient solution using rank(). But here's the basic/simple way to do what you want.

```
select a.name, a.shopno, a.year, b.number, b.name
from a
join b on a.shopno = b.shopno
  and b.insert_date = (select min(insert_date) from b b2 
                       where b2.shopno = b.shopno);
```